# how to redirect the mainpage to route in Prestashop htaccess ?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns, prestashop

if I acccess  [www.domain.com/main](http://domain.com/main)I want to get[www.domain.com](http://domain.com/main) how can I do it from .htaccess using prestashop ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the following code before the # ~~start~~  comment (if using PrestaShop 1.5) or in the beginning of the file if less than 1.5

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/main/$ http://www.domain.com/
</IfModule>
```

Comment: acctually the problem was with the frendly url from prestashop. It was set to main. I leave it blank and thats all. thx for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use this RedirectMatch line on top of your .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/main/?$ /
```

Comment: Is pretashop OR some other rule forcing `/main/` URI?

Comment: RewriteRule ^main$ /index.php [QSA,L] I also use that

Comment: any ideas ?   im a newbie with this

Comment: Open your page in Firebug and see what you get in Net tab.

Comment: your code is right, but the problem was with the prestashop, I leave the frednly url blank and it works. thx for your concern